# How to test a controller in Play Framework with a functional test

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to make a functional test for a controller with the play framework version 2.5.9.

I have a controller called HomeController

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
    def index = Action.async {
        Future{
            Ok(views.html.index("Home"))
        }
     }
}
```

my view looks like this

```
@(message: String)

@main("Home") {
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
}
```

the arguments in @main are what goes in the title of the page 
and my test looks like this

```
class ApplicationTwoSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite with OneBrowserPerSuite with HtmlUnitFactory{

  implicit val ec = Implicits.global

  val homeController = new HomeController()

  implicit override lazy val app = 
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .router(Router.from{
        case GET(p"/") => homeController.index
      })
      .build()


   "The sample Controler with a server" must {

    "have home in the title" in {
      go to s"http://localhost:9000/"
      pageTitle mustBe "Home"
    }
  }

}
```

when I run the test I get back

```
must return and ok response back *** FAILED ***
"[]" was not equal to "[Home]" (ApplicationTwoSpec.scala:37)
```

What do I need to do to have it yeild a proper response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after going to the source code of both the scala test plus and playframework.

```
go to s"http://localhost:9000/"
```

should be

```
go to s"http://localhost:$port/"
```

An `implicit lazy val port` is specified in `OneServerPerSuite` trait and gets its default value from the play.api.test.Helpers package which defaults to port 19001.  If I really needed the port to be 9000 I could also override the port by using

```
implicit override lazy val port = 9000
```